# Why doesn't the Google+ API return the Gender?

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, google-api-client

I'm using the tests:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get

Neither of them returns the users Gender even though it is publicly visible.

I have also tried enabling OAuth 2.0 and still not having any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This information is available from the [/oauth2/v1/userinfo API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get).

You will need to include the OAuth 2.0 scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`.

The information can be fetched from the endpoint:
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={accessToken}`

Official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall

API Explorer:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get

Comment: How do I specify a user to retrieve data for?

Comment: You can only receive data for the authenticated user. (The user that completes the OAuth flow)

Comment: The APIs Explorer nicely demonstrates the concept:  https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get

Comment: well that defeats the purpose. The Gender is publicly available I should be able to return many users and their gender.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=114452557602978803926&_h=1& you'll see that you can use people.get() to retrieve the gender for any user who has made that information public.